# Module found when run in __init__ file, but not found when I package it and use it as in package

Tags: python, pypi

I currently finish a project and ready to put up into pypi. By standard I read, I follow this structure (

```
implement_pypi/
    __init__.py
    testing_function.py
    another_testing.py
```

I want to implement all code in init. Therefore, I try to import both testing_file and another_testing, so in init, it looks like this:

```
import testing_function
import another_testing
```

I run the init file and it is still normal.
However, when I upload the file to pypi (after packaging into dist file and upload via twine) and install it in other machine, when I try to import implement_pypi library, it shouts this error:
*No module named 'testing_function'*
I do not know why do import behave differently in two circumstances.

Comment: Your file name is testing_file, but in Trace, 'testing_function' is shown. Are you sure that you are importing testing_file instead of testing_function?

Comment: Yes I type the question wrong, I mean import testing_function. Thank you, I fix the question

Comment: Make your `__init__.py` file empty. No need to add the import statements in the `__init__.py` file. https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#regular-packages